# My cat is snoring!

Tags: verbs, conjugations

I want to say "My cat is snoring!"  I found the verb to snore is 「いびき」and Jisho.org says it's a ["godan verb with ku ending"](http://jisho.org/word/%E9%BC%BE%E3%82%92%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F).  I haven't learned what that means, so I tried the -ku conjugations from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#Summary_of_verb_conjugations), but nothing lead to "is snoring," at least according to Google Translate.  The closest I got was 「うちの猫はいびきいた」, "my cat was snoring."

What am I missing?

Comment: The title made me think the question belonged on http://pets.stackexchange.com :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the dictionary, いびき is a noun:
いびき【鼾】snoring 
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/4267/meaning/m0u/%E9%BC%BE/

There is no such a verb as いびく.
In order to make it into a verb, you have to say 鼾をかく.
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/edc/16000261601/meaning/m0u/%E9%BC%BE%E3%82%92%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F/

So it becomes 
うちの猫はいびきをかいている。

Comment: I see, so in Japanese there's no verb "to snore," but you can turn the noun into one by adding 「をかく」.  Is を still acting as a particle when you do this?

Comment: Yes, を is still a particle.

Answer (score 3):

The entry mentions 「鼾｛いびき｝をかく」. The verb you need to conjugate is かく. いびき itself is a noun.

> My cat is snoring!
>   = うちの猫が*いびきを**かいている**！
>    <sub>*Use が, not は.</sub>

To sound casual and colloquial, you could say:

> うちの猫、いびきかいてる！

leaving out the particles が and を.

Comment: 質問には「I want to say "My cat **is** snoring!"」とありますので、現在形になるのでは？(かいていた→かいている) ・・・あと、「は」より「が」のほうがいいような気が・・・(「うちの猫**が**いびきをかいてる！」) 口語的には「うちの猫、いびきかいてる！」になっちゃうでしょうけど。

Comment: @chocolate そうですね、質問者の文を見て書いてしまった。

Comment: 編集さして～！　まずかったら直してね～

Comment: @chocolate はいは～い＾＿＿＾。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 3):

The verb *ibiku* used to be a regularly conjugating verb that had the same pattern as 引{ひ}く, apparently derived as a compound of 息{い} (more commonly *iki*) + 引{ひ}く.  My big copy of Shogakukan's 国語{こくご}大{だい}辞典{じてん} lists this as a 四段{よだん}活用{かつよう}動詞{どうし}, the predecessor to modern 五段{ごだん}活用{かつよう}動詞{どうし}.  This generally refers to verbs that fell out of common use before the modern era.  In this case, *ibiku* is not used any more, but the stem and noun form *ibiki* persists.  As other posters have noted, this noun requires the verb *kaku* (roughly, "to scratch out [a snore]"), or (less commonly) *tateru* ("to put up [a snore]").  In a pinch, you could say *ibiki o suru* and people would understand what you mean.